# How do you initialize a 1 dimensional array when you do not know the size in C#?

Tags: c#

I had been trying really hard about initializing a 1 dimensional array without knowing its size, but dont get it;
Please tell me how can I declare a array whose size will dynamically increase as per the requirement in C#.

I mean, want to do something like this

```
class A
{
    int[] myarray;
    int i=0;
    while(i<5)
    {
        myarray[i]==n;
        n=n%10;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Please Help !!!

Comment: The answer is different in each language. Which language are you actually using?

Comment: But in your example you know that it is `int[5]`

Comment: If I fix your code formatting, please don't remove it again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User can also declare this type of array using ARRAYLIST

System.Collections namespace defines a class known as ArrayList that can store dynamic sized array of objects.

```
   ArrayList cities = new ArrayList();
   cities.Add("Pune");
   cities.Add("Mumbai");
```

Answer (score 5):

In C you would have to work with Malloc and Realloc, in C# you should prefer a List.

```
Class A {
   List<int> integerList = new List<int>();

   void DoSometing() {   
   for(int i = 0; i < somewhat; i++) {
         integerList.Add(i);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: realloc is evil, don't go there.

Comment: Well when you resize an STL vector past its capacity then it will allocate a new block, copy the data across and then free the original block.  Which is ... erm ... what realloc does.  I would imagine C#'s list does the same.

Answer (score 1):

In C++:

```
 #include <vector>

 // ...

 std::vector<int> myVector;  // will resize as you 'push_back'
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions in the languages are:

C: `malloc()` and `realloc()`

C++: `std::vector`

C#: `List`

Answer (score 0):

In C you use a malloc of a pointer.
In C++ you could just use a std::vector< T >.
In C# use a List< T >.

ie in C use a pointer in C++ and C# use one of the handy container classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy...

```
int IAmTheSize = 183475; // just a random int. Replace it with your value.
int[] myArray = new int[IAmTheSize];
```

You can initialize the array(s) with any size.
But if you don't know the precise size it will have, you might want to have a look at the `List<>` class.

```
List<int> myList;

int i=0;
while(i < 5)
{
    myList.Add(n);
    n = n % 10;
    i++;
}
```

From the operations you do, I realize this is some sort of exercising.
BTW, assigning a value in the array is done with the `=` operator, like `myarray[i]=n;`, **not** `myarray[i]==n;` (will return a bool/boolean/logical value actually).

---

You can read more about the `List<>` class here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx